# How can I open a link in the default web browser from an HTA?

Tags: javascript, browser, hta

I'm working on an application that is implemented as an HTA. I have a series of links that I would like to have open in the system's default web browser. Using `<a href="url" target="_blank">` opens the link in IE regardless of the default browser.

Is there a way to use the default browser? Using JavaScript is an option.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Create a shell and attempt to run a URL.

This works for me (save as whatever.hta and execute it) on my system. Clicking on the button opens Google in Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>HTA Test</title>
  <hta:application applicationname="HTA Test" scroll="yes" singleinstance="yes">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function openURL()
  {
      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      shell.run("http://www.google.com");
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="openURL()" value="Open Google">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This only works when implemented in IE. Not in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @Siyah HTAs are run using the IE engine: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application#Execution

Comment: I want to download a file that i have created using blob. How to do it in HTA. It is working fine in chrome. But gives error "Access Denied" in HTA

Answer (score -2):

Nope, sadly I believe this is a browser specific implementation that will open new links with target="_blank" within the same browser.

If you wanted to open it in the default browser, then you would need to interact with the OS, which JavaScript cannot do.

Comment: JScript inside an HTA gets to run in the "Local" security zone, so it can access a lot more of the OS, including ActiveX.