# How to open a link inside an iframe from a hta in the default browser

Tags: javascript, iframe, browser, hta

What I need is just like [How can I open a link in the default web browser from an HTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/185423/66372), but with the restriction that the link sits inside an iframe.

The iframe's loads a page in our server.

Idea: can the iframe's redirect be detected & prevented, so then we'd run code like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/185581/66372. How?

**Update 1**
To be clear: the problem we're trying to solve is that when **the user** clicks on any link, it opens in the default browser.

One option similar to mplungjan's answer, is to capture the click event for all links in the iframe's DOM. Is there a more generic option that works at the iframe, document or body level? (and thus also works with delayed loads and any other tricks)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224816

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the link, but that's like in the linked question. Problem is the link is inside an iframe.

Comment: So grab the link in the hta first. Load the page in an iframe in the HTA, grab the link and then trigger the browser with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, which should be perfectly allowed in an HTA which has elevated rights

```
window.onload=function() {
  window.frames["iframe_in_this_document"].onload=function() {
    var links = this.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
      url = links[i].href;
      if (url) links[i].onclick=function() {
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        shell.run(this.href);
        return false;
      }
   }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I wanted, but it points a valid solution. Updated the question in case someone knows a more general solution.

Comment: See update. It will trigger on any link loaded in the page onload. Use setTimeout if you want to try and catch delayed load

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick, took out all delayed loading on the page. I did run into issues trying to hook onload in that way (even tried attachEvent), but only managed to do it by setting it like this in the iframe: onload="iframeLoaded();". Note even this didn't work: onload="iframeLoaded". Maybe the function was supposed to have some argument? (I got no error on it though).