# Is it possible to open a link in IE when using Chrome without using the Chrome IE tab extension?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

I hope I am asking this in correct place.

I have been asked to look into the possibility of opening certain links in IE browser from Chrome (will be set as default browser in our organisation). The reason is that some oracle applications are not supported in Chrome and must open in IE.

I have been told the chrome IE Tab extension is not fit for purpose in this case.

The majority of my research so far has indicated its not possible except in one case where it was suggested to use ActiveX see example below:
(The original source is from [How can I open a link in the default web browser from an HTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185423/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-the-default-web-browser-from-an-hta))

```
function openURL()
  {
      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      shell.run("http://www.google.com");
  }
```

I've played around a bit with this and keep getting the error 'Automation server can't create object'

Is it possible to open a link in IE when using Chrome without using the Chrome IE tab extension?

If so what's the best method?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look into writing a simple Chrome extension specifically for your needs.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted