# opening microsoft edge or chrome or (another browser (cascading)) on hyperlink

Tags: html

```html
<a href="microsoft-edge:https://www.mywebsite.com/">Register</a>
```

Above is my current a href tag.
Here's what I want to do:

For example I'm currently on google chrome, I want the link above be opened first on Microsoft edge, and the user doesn't have it, it would open internet explorer, if not google chrome, if not opera... etc.

ALSO. When I open the link, it also opens on the browser I'm using. How do I make it 'not' open on my current browser and only on the new one?

Thanks in advance. I'm using this on a patcher for a game I'm making, in-case you're wondering.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that

Comment: This [stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185423/how-can-i-open-a-link-in-the-default-web-browser-from-an-hta) answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Its actually impossible to do it..
You can try creating custom domain using registry for testing purposes only..